# How to add an onclick event on a newly added row (DataTables)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, onclick, event-handling

I'm adding rows dynamically using

```
table.row.add
```

and I want to, for every row that is added to the table, to also add an onclick event to that row so it links to a URL.

So, how do I refer to the row that has just been added to add this event?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `onclick` to this event :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example').DataTable( {
      "createdRow": function ( row, data, index )
       {
           // here
       }
    } );
 } );
```

Comment: But how do I reference the created row directly after it has been created?

Comment: @SamPrice look at **https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow** or you can just use a delegated event handler.