# How can I make a newly created row clickable to a URL? (DataTables)

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables, href

```
$.getJSON('/stData/' + article, function (data) {
    $.each(data.response, function (inc) { 
        data.response[inc].Subject, data.response[inc].Summary]);
    });
    table2.draw();
```

The function above simply creates a DataTable using a JSON request. I want, at the same time, to make the row clickable for every row using a URL from the JSON request, so when clicked it opens the corresponding URL.

Comment: `<a href="url">Something fun</a>` ?

Comment: That doesn't make the row clickable

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times.  You asked 7 days ago here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596062/how-to-add-an-onclick-event-on-a-newly-added-row-datatables The question has been ansered many, many times before, and is discussed heavily in the datatables.net forum.